# How to create a section to show the latest posts for a particular label on blogger?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, blogger

the problem is the following I have all the code and functional, to have a section of recent posts by labbel in blogger, which can be seen [here on the Android area](https://trit3k.blogspot.com/). But since I do not have much experience in javascript and the code is all javascript, I ask you to help solve this.

So, if someone could help me I would like to have all the posts side by side (automatically, for example, when I reached post number 2 that would be the most right 3 would already be on the left, 4 on the right side , and always so by this sequence), with the style of the first post that is inside a red square, which you can see in the image below.

[image]

The JavaScript code is this. I hope you can help me, thanks in advance.

```js
//<![CDATA[
function labelthumbs(t) {
    for (var e = 0; e < numposts; e++) {
        var n, r = t.feed.entry[e],
            m = r.title.$t;
        if (e == t.feed.entry.length) break;
        for (var i = 0; i < r.link.length; i++) {
            if ("replies" == r.link[i].rel && "text/html" == r.link[i].type) var l = r.link[i].title,
                o = r.link[i].href;
            if ("alternate" == r.link[i].rel) {
                n = r.link[i].href;
                break
            }
        }
        var u;
        try {
            u = r.media$thumbnail.url, u = u.replace("/s72-c/", "/w" + thumb_width + "-h" + thumb_height + "-c/")
        } catch (h) {
            s = r.content.$t, a = s.indexOf("<img"), b = s.indexOf('src="', a), c = s.indexOf('"', b + 5), d = s.substr(b + 5, c - b - 5), u = -1 != a && -1 != b && -1 != c && "" != d ? d : no_thumb
        }
        var p = r.published.$t,
            w = p.substring(0, 4),
            _ = p.substring(5, 7),
            f = p.substring(8, 10),
            g = new Array;
        g[1] = "Janeiro", g[2] = "Feveiro", g[3] = "Março", g[4] = "Abril", g[5] = "Maio", g[6] = "Junnho", g[7] = "Julho", g[8] = "Agosto", g[9] = "Setember", g[10] = "October", g[11] = "Novembro", g[12] = "Dezembro", document.write('<span class="newsmartpik_left">'), document.write('<ul class="newsmartpik_thumbs">'), document.write("<li>"), 1 == showpostthumbnails && document.write('<div class="block-image2"><div class="thumb2"><a href="' + n + '"><span class="rollover"></span><img width="' + thumb_width + '" height="' + thumb_height + '" alt="' + m + '" src="' + u + '"/></a></div></div>'), document.write('<span class="newsmartpik_title"><a href="' + n + '" target ="_top">' + m + "</a></span>");
        var v = "";
        if (document.write('<span class="newsmartpik_meta">'), 1 == showpostdate && (v = v + '<span class="newsmartpik_meta_date">' + g[parseInt(_)] + " " + f + ", " + w + "</span>"), 1 == showcommentnum && ("1 Comments" == l && (l = "1 Comments"), "0 Comments" == l && (l = "0 Comments"), showcomment = '<span class="newsmartpik_meta_comment"><a href="' + o + '">' + l + "</a></span>", v += showcomment), 1 == displaymore && (v = v + '<span class="newsmartpik_meta_more"><a href="' + n + '" class="url" target ="_top">Read More...</a></span>'), document.write(v), document.write("</span>"), document.write('<span class="newsmartpik_summary">'), "content" in r) var y = r.content.$t;
        else if ("summary" in r) var y = r.summary.$t;
        else var y = "";
        var k = /<\S[^>]*>/g;
        if (y = y.replace(k, ""), 1 == showpostsummary)
            if (y.length < numchars) document.write(""), document.write(y), document.write("");
            else {
                document.write(""), y = y.substring(0, numchars);
                var $ = y.lastIndexOf(" ");
                y = y.substring(0, $), document.write(y + "..."), document.write("")
            }
        document.write("</span>"), document.write("</li>"), document.write("</ul>"), document.write("</span>")
    }
    document.write('<span class="newsmartpik_right">'), document.write('<ul class="newsmartpik_thumbs">');
    for (var e = 1; e < numposts2; e++) {
        var n, r = t.feed.entry[e],
            m = r.title.$t;
        if (e == t.feed.entry.length) break;
        for (var i = 1; i < r.link.length; i++) {
            if ("replies" == r.link[i].rel && "text/html" == r.link[i].type) var l = r.link[i].title,
                o = r.link[i].href;
            if ("alternate" == r.link[i].rel) {
                n = r.link[i].href;
                break
            }
        }
        var x;
        try {newsmartpik_left
            x = r.media$thumbnail.url.replace("/s72-c/", "/w" + thumb_width2 + "-h" + thumb_height2 + "-c/")
        } catch (h) {
            s = r.content.$t, a = s.indexOf("<img"), b = s.indexOf('src="', a), c = s.indexOf('"', b + 5), d = s.substr(b + 5, c - b - 5), x = -1 != a && -1 != b && -1 != c && "" != d ? d : no_thumb2
        }
        var p = r.published.$t,
            w = p.substring(0, 4),
            _ = p.substring(5, 7),
            f = p.substring(8, 10);
        1 == showpostthumbnails2 && document.write('<div class="block-image2"><div class="thumb2"><a href="' + n + '"><img width="' + thumb_width2 + '" height="' + thumb_height2 + '" alt="' + m + '" src="' + x + '"/></a></div></div>'), document.write("<li>"), document.write('<span class="newsmartpik_title newsmartpik_title2"><a href="' + n + '" target ="_top">' + m + "</a></span>");
        var v = "";
        document.write('<span class="newsmartpik_meta newsmartpik_meta2">'), 1 == showpostdate2 && (v = v + '<span class="newsmartpik_meta_date">' + g[parseInt(_)] + " " + f + ", " + w + "</span>"), 1 == showcommentnum2 && ("1 Comment" == l && (l = "1 Comments"), "0 Comment" == l && (l = "0 Comments"), showcomment = '<span class="newsmartpik_meta_comment newsmartpik_meta_comment2"><a href="' + o + '">' + l + "</a></span>", v += showcomment), 1 == displaymore2 && (v = v + '<span class="newsmartpik_meta_more newsmartpik_meta_more2"><a href="' + n + '" class="url" target ="_top">Ler Mais</a></span>'), document.write(v), document.write("</span>"), document.write("</li>")
    }
    document.write("</ul>"), document.write("</span>")
}
//]]>
```

```js
var numposts = 1,
    numposts2 = 4,
    showpostthumbnails = !0,
    showpostthumbnails2 = !0,
    displaymore = !1,
    displaymore2 = !1,
    showcommentnum = !0,
    showcommentnum2 = !1,
    showpostdate = !0,
    showpostdate2 = !0,
    showpostsummary = !0,
    numchars = 75,
    thumb_width = 370,
    thumb_height = 250,
    thumb_width2 = 370,
    thumb_height2 = 250,
    no_thumb = & quot;
https: //lh3.googleusercontent.com/-htHpxFoFKFU/VtfvuTf4DwI/AAAAAAAAEVM/nJicgrZGWlk/s340-Ic42/newsmartpik_thumb.png&quot;,no_thumb2=&quot; https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-v1FrVSrWAI4/VtfvuOMgx0I/AAAAAAAAEVI/dF8p7IUnk1k/s100-Ic42/newsmartpikthumb_small.png&quot;;
```